# vim map toggle key to make JSLint

Tags: vim

I have installed nodejs and jslint and created javascript.vim file in ftplugin directory. javascript.vim containes the following lines:

```
setlocal makeprg=jslint\ %
setlocal errorformat=%f:%l:%c:%m

nmap <F5> :w<CR>:make<CR>:cw<CR><CR>:copen<CR>
```

this will open quick fix window for jslint reported errors. Now I would like to use F5 as toggle key on first F5 run make and show error window on second F5 close error window.

I have created the following code for this

```
setlocal makeprg=jslint\ %
setlocal errorformat=%f:%l:%c:%m

let s:showMakeWnd = "0"
function! ToggleMake()
    echo "Make Wnd mode: " . s:showMakeWnd

    if s:showMakeWnd == "0"
        execute ":w<CR>:make<CR>:cw<CR>:copen<CR>"
    elseif
        execute ":cclose<CR>"
    endif

    let s:showMakeWnd = (s:showMakeWnd == "0" ? "1" : "0")
endfunction

nmap <F5> :call ToggleMake()<CR>
```

but after I press F5 I get the following error:

```
"<CR>:make<CR>:cw<CR>:copen<CR>"
Error detected while processing function ToggleMake:
line 10:
"<CR>:make<CR>:cw<CR>:copen<CR>" E212: Can't open file for writing
```

Comment: Are you in the quickfix window when you hit `<F5>` and get that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`execute` executes *Ex* commands. And you only need it to expand variables, which you are not doing, so

```
execute ":w<CR>:make<CR>:cw<CR>:copen<CR>"
```

you should write

```
w
make
cw
copen
```

The syntax you wanted is for the `normal` command

```
norm :w<CR>:make<CR>:cw<CR>:copen<CR>
```

but it's needlessly more fragile (and I am not really sure about the special characters here; common usage is `exe "norm something"` where *something* gets some variable substitutions.